# R: layout saving as png

Tags: r

I have four charts (type: ggplot2)and am trying to save them as a png. However when I run the code below only ch4 gets saved.

```
png(filename = fname, width = 900, height = 600, units = 'px')
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
ch1
ch2
ch3
ch4
dev.off()
```

I would be grateful to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should do the layout before calling png()?

Comment: If they're ggplot2 plots you might need to try `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package, I don't think the base layout functions work.

Comment: adam.888, the 'ggplot' functions overwrite any layout or viewport specifications, so what you're not seeing is that each one of those 'ggplot' commands is using the entire page and overwriting the previous chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot2 graphs can be layed out on a single page using `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c(1, 4, 9))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))
p1 <- p + geom_point(colour="red")
p2 <- p + geom_point(colour="blue")
p3 <- p + geom_point(colour="green")
p4 <- p + geom_point(colour="purple")

library(gridExtra)
png(filename="test.png", width=600, height=600)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ah, good.  I was starting to wonder when someone would package up your comment into a proper answer.  The 'grid.arrange' function is definitely the one to use here, since you otherwise can't specify viewports for the 'ggplot' functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grid.arrange` instead of `layout`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
ch1 <- qplot(1,2)
ch2 <- qplot(1,2)
ch3 <- qplot(1,2)
ch4 <- qplot(1,2)

png(filename = "fname.png", width = 900, height = 600, units = 'px')
grid.arrange(ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4, ncol = 2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

You could use `layout` function for base base plotting. Note that the file extension has to be specified inside `""`:

```
png(filename = "fname.png", width = 900, height = 600, units = 'px')
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1,2)
plot(1,2)
plot(1,2)
plot(1,2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Using a variable to specify the filename isn't the problem.  I do that all the time.

Comment: Well, (type: ggplot2) was added after I wrote the first answer (or I did not see it at least). I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your answer would be helpful if you dropped the insistence on 'fname' being the problem.  The OP stated that output is being produced, but only the last chart is written into the PNG file.  A PNG file is clearly being outputted, so 'fname' does not need to be modified.